# Alter Users Table in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently in the WP-ADMIN the Users Table show info like Gravatar, Name, Email, Role and Posts. How can I alter this table to display other info like Phone, Company, etc?

PS: These metadata infos already exists and are displayed when I click on a user but I want it to be displayed in the table too.

Comment: There should be a callback you can register to, so to add columns of your choice. But I don't remember the name from top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *probably* going to have to manually rewrite the html table in wp-admin/users.php as currently it's produced via an object which doesn't contain the User's meta data.

You'd need to access the meta data using the function [get_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta):

```
<?php get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single); ?>
```

Be aware, changing this isn't a great idea as it may break next time you upgrade Wordpress.

Comment: @mattjgalloway In a WP Update, user tables is altered, or dropped?

Comment: @StevenV, this question is probably very out of date, it's from 2013, so everything has changed in WP pretty much